# Fieldset CSS: any way to get a consistent display between Chrome, Firefox and IE?

Tags: css, cross-browser, fieldset

I'm trying to get the display of a fieldset the same across browsers.  I've create a simple file:

```
<style>
  fieldset
  {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  legend
  {
    color: #696969;
  }
</style>

<fieldset style="width: 440px; float: left;">
  <legend>First Fieldset</legend>
  <table width="310px">
    <tr>
      <td>
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
<br clear="all" />
<fieldset style="float: left; width: 440px; padding-top: 10px;">
  <legend>Second Fieldset</legend>
  <div id="innerDiv">
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td>
          &nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<br clear="all" />
<fieldset style="float: right; width: 300px">
  <legend>Third Fieldset</legend>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 350px; border: solid 1px black;">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Chrome 3.0 and FF 3.6 render this almost the same - the fieldset border is a bit heavier on Chrome, and a there's noticeable stairstepping on the corners.  IE has a slightly thinner border, but the corners seem to be a bit tighter.

Is there any way to get all three browsers to display this the same way?

Comment: i'm sure your problems will be much smaller if you dont nest empty tables into a form or stop using the style attribute and start to use the class attribute

Comment: Well, there's actually a bunch of crap in there, formatted in tables - but I'm really concerned with the borders, which shouldn't really be affected by the fact there are empty tables in this example.

Comment: border-radius doesn't work in IE at all.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to create curved corners. To do this in IE curvycorners is a great option: http://www.curvycorners.net/demos/. Just add the script and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a [reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Edit: Upon further review, it already contains fieldset, so no need to add that..

Comment: If I use a reset, then I have to specify the border properties to get the outline, and then IE goes back to square corners.

Comment: This attempt to solve every problem with 'css reset' has got to stop.